# How do I use the flood interface?

Tags: 8

I'm working on a two-factor login form that sends a text message to the user. With a "did not recieve message" button. I would like to limit the number of times a user can request for a new text message.

I know that I can register flood for a certain event like: `\Drupal::flood()->register('eventName', 1800, $user->getUuid())`. The FloodInterface has a `isAllowed($name, $threshold, $window = 3600, $identifier = NULL);` method that, I imagine, tests when a user tries to do a certain `$name` event, it tests if that event has been done more often than the `$threshold` within the `$window`. If so then the method returns `false` and otherwise `true`.

In my example I can register the event somewhere in the chain of events/functions that send the message and also check there if the event `isAllowed`?

Something like so:?

```php
public function someFunction() {
  \Drupal::flood()->register('send message', 900, $user->getUuid());
  $token = 12345;
  $this->sendMessage($token);
}

private function sendMessage($token) {
  $is_allowed = \Drupal::flood()->isAllowed('send message', 3, 900, $user->getUuid());
  if ($is_allowed) {
    // Send the message
  }
}
```

What I don't get is why I also have to indicate the `$window` in the `isAllowed` method when I already assign that in the register method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are two different parameters that share the same name (and can share the same value by default). Per the docs for [`FloodInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Flood%21FloodInterface.php/interface/FloodInterface/9.0.x):

- `::register()`:

  - > int $window: (optional) Number of seconds before this event expires. Defaults to 3600 (1 hour). Typically uses the same value as the isAllowed() $window parameter. Expired events are purged on cron run to prevent the flood table from growing indefinitely.
- `::isAllowed()`:

  - > int $window: (optional) Number of seconds in the time window for this event (default is 3600 seconds, or 1 hour).

The `register()` parameter specifies how long that flood event will be stored (remembered) after the time of registration before `::garbageCollection()` clears it out. The `isAllowed()` parameter specifies the max number of instances that can occur within that window before `isAllowed()` will return `FALSE`

Comment: So I get the difference between the two $window variables. But it's not clear to me if the $itentifier for the `::isAllowed` method will use the same value that you used when registering the even when you do not include it in the `isAllowed::` call.

Comment: It will depend on the implementing class of course, but the default for core flood classes is to use the client IP address when `$identifer` hasn't been specified. 

To make things more concrete, take a look @ [`DatabaseBackend`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Flood%21DatabaseBackend.php/class/DatabaseBackend/9.0.x) class that implements the interface via the `flood` table.